# I got a jump in reputation that only shows on the main site, where did it come from?

Tags: bug, reputation

I received 102 extra reputation in one second and I can't find the cause. Here is my [reputation page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3064877/user2346536?tab=reputation).

Is this a bug? The reputation change only shows up on the main site.

[image]

Comment: I believe that is the association bonus.

Comment: Nice... I feel like a member of the family now !

Comment: Welcome to the family, make sure to pay your dues or risk getting whacked!

Comment: Also, the reason it's not on Meta yet: Caching. Your Meta rep is cached, and will take a few minutes to update to reflect your rep on main.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to your profile page and look under the reputation tab you'll see that it is an [Association Bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus), which you're awarded at 200 reputation.

[image: association bonus]

> The bonus is awarded because you have proven that you know your way
>   around the basic features of any Stack Exchange website, and with
>   those 100 extra points you can now comment, vote, flag and create
>   bounties on all SE sites.
>
> From here on out, on any new sites you join you'll also be given this
>   bonus.

Comment: Reminds me of the day I got it.  I went to lunch and came back to find +525 in my notifications.  SO got a +15:answer, which put me over 200, which immediately added 100 to Arcade, Worldbuilding, Game Development, and one other (PP&CG?).  Which put Worldbuilding (or Game Dev) over 200, which in turn bumped SO (unless SO being over 200 grants the +100 to itself, but I like my interpretation more).  Glorious cascade of rep bonuses.

Answer (score 5):

Congratulations, you've received an [association bonus](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)!

> site association bonus: +100 on each site (awarded a maximum of one time per site)

You've reached this because your reputation hit 200 here on Stack Overflow, which immediately jumped it to 300+.  Your reputation history states as much.

As a note, the only thing you'd be able to see on Meta is the actual net rep, not where it came from.